# getting error for simple mysql insert

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

```
INSERT INTO `comments` 
  ( `id`, `pid`, `comment`, `user`, `date`, `active`) 
VALUES 
   ('23','3','Most Excellent!  I am using it right now as you can see and would never even consider different shopping cart software... I''ve tried them all and found them lacking the freedom to do it my way ;)','Admin','2010-12-08 21:00:07','1');
```

Error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Most Excellent! I am using it right now as you can see and would never even co' at line 1

It's got me baffled?! I replaced the single quote for "I've" and I still get the error

- PHP 5.3.6
- Mysql 5.5.10

  ```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `comments`;
  CREATE TABLE `comments` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `pid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `comment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `user` varchar(25) DEFAULT '0',
    `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );
  ```

Comment: Your query looks correct. Can you show us the schema of the table "comments"?

Comment: Well, though '' should work, you should also just try escaping it \'  Also, a habit I always got into, it is a good idea to base_64 the text before you enter it into the database (another safeguard against sql injections).  Then just decode it on the way out.

Comment: I just glued that down and can see the problem.. the comment table needs to be text DOH!

Comment: Read my modified comment about base64'ng

Comment: nope... no go with a text column either.. man this sucks!

Comment: I use a scrub function that makes sql injection a thing of the past as well as header injections. but why won't this insert? too wierd, I think it's possessed :0

Comment: the base_64 encode thing is a thought though if I can't get it to import. I'm working on a mysql import and that is the code that is generated so far and it looks clean, no comments either just straight import... man!

Comment: one thing I did notice though was when I export with PHP MyAdmin the first two values are not quotationed ie: VALUES (23,3,'Most Excellent!... and I am wondering if this has something to do with it since that will import no problem??? Makes no sense???

Comment: @Tom About the PMA Export, it doesn't quote number fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get the exact same error if I break the query this way:

```
INSERT INTO `comments` ( `id`, `pid`, `comment`, `user`, `date`, `active`) VALUES ('23','3','Most Excellent!  I am using it right now as you can see and would never even co
```

(Tested on MySql 5.1.41.)

I guess the string which contains the query is being broken at position 179~180. Try inspect the query string in your PHP code right before the query execution.

Comment: I'm using the SQL part of PMA to create the table and to test inserts.

Comment: $file=fread(fopen($path.$file, "r"), filesize($path.$file));
 $query=explode(";",$file);
 for ($i=0;$i < count($query)-1;$i++) {
  @mysql_db_query($db_name,$query[$i],$conn) or die(mysql_error());
  
 } // that is how I am importing must be the issue some how

Comment: one of my comments above wasn't listed but if you export with PMA the first two values are not quoted ie: VALUES (23,3,'Most Excellent! and that will import no prob... stupid error and I have no way to do that if numeric won't work either because not all are like that just that one for some reason?

Comment: In this case, the `$query=explode(";",$file)` is breaking the queries whenever it finds a ";", _including_ inside a string! You must find other way, like `$query = split(';(\r|\n|\r\n)', $file)` (assuming there is one insert by line).

Comment: great point! that should heal it... I hope.. thanks! but still leaves me wondering because that insert wasn't broken by ;

Comment: see my comment above on the PMA no quotes

Comment: oops... it was broken that way.. good eye Sony Santos! Thank you man! u2 mazzzzz

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet to vote you up but I tried :)

Comment: You're welcome! Thank's for trying to vote me up! I'm glad to help you!